# ASP.NET MVC: Enforce AJAX request on an action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, actionmethod, controller-action

I'm looking for a way to enforce a controller's action to be accessed only via an AJAX request.

**What is the best way to do this before the action method is called?** I want to refactor the following from my action methods:

```
if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    // Do something
else
    // return an error of some sort
```

What I'm envisioning is an `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute` that can be used like the `[AcceptVerbs]` attribute.  I have no experience crating such a custom attribute though.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Create an ActionFilter that fires OnActionExecuting

```
public class AjaxActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(//path to error message);           
    }
}
```

Setting the filter's Result property will prevent execution of the ActionMethod.

You can then apply it as an attribute to your ActionMethods.

Comment: +1, of the ways presented, this is by and far the one closest to my preferred approach and is extensible, especially if sited in a basecontroller that all others inherit from

Answer (score 2):

Its as simple as this:

```
public class AjaxOnly : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        return controllerContext.HttpContext.IsAjaxRequest();
    }
}
```

I just forget where IsAjaxRequest() comes from, I'm pasting from code I have but "lost" that method.  ;)

Comment: Ooops, didn't get the part about returning an error.  This makes it so the method will never get his unless the request is Ajax.  Just another way to do it.

Comment: I know this answer was posted aaaaaages ago but the IsAjaxRequest hangs off the request object not the Httpcontext.