# How do I redirect ChildActionOnly requests to my custom 404?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my application I wish to block the ability for users to navigate to specific views from the browser. These `ActionResults` and by extension `Views` serve singular basic functions to which I call in my layout with `Html.RenderAction("Action","Controller")`. In order to handle this, I am using `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute on the various get requests. How would I go about redirecting these request to my custom 404 instead of the error page?

I have tried setting the `ActionResult` to private which does send the user to a 404, however doing so causes the `Html.RenderAction`to fail.

Here is my Web.config logic

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
  <error redirect="~/Error/NotFound" statusCode="404" />
</customErrors>
```

Comment: You cannot redirect in a `[ChildActionOnly]` method - [Why are Redirect Results not allowed in Child Actions in Asp.net MVC 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056421/why-are-redirect-results-not-allowed-in-child-actions-in-asp-net-mvc-2)

Comment: You might be better served to make a custom data attribute for your "ajax only" action methods that will allow you to redirect if requested directly.  Here is a great SO solution I've used before for exactly this problem - https://stackoverflow.com/a/4168806/130387

Comment: There is no Ajax request in this particular case